# I am trying to run vagrant but it is causing error

Tags: terminal, vagrant, virtual-machine, mozilla, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to run vagrant up but this error is showing in my console:
Besides this, I also run vagrant destroy but it was not working.

```
 error while creating domain: Error saving the server: Call to virDomainDefineXML failed: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
```

Comment: Try upgrading  your version of libvirt

Comment: But how to upgrade the libvirt version I mean which command I need to run?  @RamanSailopal

Comment: Depends on your distro.